# Counting occurrences of a string in a column of a csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, pandas

I have a large csv file (over 66k rows) and I want to count the number of times a string appears in each row. I am focusing on one column in particular and each row in that column has a small sentence, as shown below:

```
Example of data:
Sam ate an apple and she felt great
Jill thinks the sky is purple but Bob says it's blue
Ralph wants to go apple picking this fall
```

I know how to do this for text files but I'm having difficulty applying the same techniques to csv. I have been using pandas and have tried a couple of methods but they return error codes or empty dataframes.

```
Attempts:
my_file = "NEISS2014.csv"
df = pandas.read_csv(my_file)

df.groupby(df['sentence'].map(lambda x:'apple' if 'apple' in x else x)).sum()
df[df['sentence'].str.contains("apple") == True]
```

If anyone could help me debug this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with column `sentence`:

```
print df
#                                            sentence
#0    Sam ate an apple and she felt great apple apple
#1  Jill thinks the sky is purple but Bob says it'...
#2          Ralph wants to go apple picking this fall

print df.columns
#Index([u'sentence'], dtype='object')

df['count'] = df['sentence'].str.count('apple')
print df
#                                            sentence  count
#0    Sam ate an apple and she felt great apple apple      3
#1  Jill thinks the sky is purple but Bob says it'...      0
#2          Ralph wants to go apple picking this fall      1
```

Comment: I've tried this before and it didn't work. When I try to run the code I get an error that says: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sentence'

Comment: Try change `df.sentence` to `df['sentence']`.

Comment: df['sentence'].str.count("apple") ended up working! I'm not sure why I needed to have double quotes around apple, but that seemed to fix it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Comment: How might you go about searching through a list of words (for example, 'apple', 'orange','pear',etc.)? could you still use str.count() or would you need to use another fundtion?

Comment: @CjV - Use `L = ['apple','orange','pear']` and then `df['count'] = df['sentence'].str.count('|'.join(L))`